# Erro para configurar Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress

Eu instalei o wordpress em um servidor, e funcionou tudo certinho, entretanto quando tento adicionar a função:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
```

Todas as páginas aparecem o seguinte erro:

> "Erro ao estabelecer uma conexão com o Banco de Dados"

Aparentemente o wordpress não está criando algumas tabelas necessárias, mas é uma instalação nova e quando comento a linha do multisite ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui solucionar, na verdade estava seguindo um tutorial que não estava certo, foi necessário adicionar apenas o seguinte código inicialmente:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

E executar a instalação pelo painel de admin Ferramentas -> Instalação de Rede, e ai sim colar o texto que ele gera, que tem a instrução de define('MULTISITE', true);